# Protect pointers on minor heap during callback from C

Tags: c, garbage-collection, ocaml

I have a scenario where a C-library takes a `float array` as an argument and (somewhere further down the road) calls a OCaml function:

```
    -------------
    | a) OCaml  |   p : value (float array)
    -------------
        ||          
        \/
    ---------
    | b) C  |       p : double*
    ---------
        ||          
        \/
    ------------
    | c) OCaml |    p : value (float array)
    ------------
```

In principle, due to OCaml's clever memory layout, one can directly pass the `value` as a `double*` into the C-library and everything-just-works (TM). That is, until there is some allocation happening in part c).

When the GC decides to cleanup the minor heap, the double* pointer may become invalid. Since this can only happen to parameters in b), I'd like to signal the GC "do whatever you want, but never move the content in these blocks until I tell you so". Is there a way to achieve this using the OCaml API?

Comment: I dont know about ocaml but sounds like you sould stick your array in a variable to increase its refcount and forbid the GC to collect it.

Comment: The problem is not to keep that variable alive, but to keep it from being moved around by the generational GC.

Comment: There's been some discussion here ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fa.caml/jp98NhjAaRM ) about Ocaml's GC moving things around between Ocaml->C->Ocaml chains.

Comment: How much do you need that feature ? Isn't copying your float (in C code) enough ? Can't you ask your OCaml function to return the new float pointer ? As a provisional solution, you can disable the GC by setting the minor heap to a big size.

Answer (score 1):

A bigarray would be the proper way to solve this problem, but it means that you cannot just pass the `double *` pointer from C to OCaml, you have to keep track of the custom block that represents the bigarray.

There is another way, although it is less elegant and less robust: you can make sure that the `float array` doesn't move by doing both of the following:

1. force a minor collection at some point after it is allocated (call `Gc.minor`)
2. forbid compactions (use `Gc.set` to set `max_overhead` to 1000000)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom block as described in a [manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-400/manual033.html#toc146). But I'd suggest you a better solution. Consider using Bigarrays.

Comment: In fact, I do (consider Bigarrays). AFAIK, a bigarray is just a custom block with a (malloc'ed) double* content, right? Could you elaborate your answer about how I would wrap that pointer from b) to c) ?

Comment: I can, but I suppose that you wouldn't like it. Thats why I haven't done it answer. Instead of referring to a float array contents directly, you need to create a custom block, and then pass a pointer that is hold inside a custom block to your c-function. But this is exactly what Bigarray does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your local value to be tracked by the GC, you should use the CAMLparam* declaration, something like `CAMLparam1(p)` instead of `double *p`.

This will allow the GC to update your value's pointer and keep it safe.

You can still profit from the `double*` trick by copying `p` into a `double* p2` with the right coercion, you'll just need to do it twice:

1. At the begining of your function.
2. Right after your callback.

So your code will look like that:

```
value myfunction (value p_v)
{
 CAMLparam1(p_v);
 double *p = (double*) p_v;

 /* actions over p */

 callback(p_v);
 p = (double*) p_v;

 /* remainder of your code */

 CAMLreturn (value_to_return);
}
```

For more on good GC interaction, you can read the [OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html#sec440).